# CADES-T signature Java8

Tags: java, soap, java-8, certificate, x509certificate

I am developing a Java application (version 8) that will call a SOAP WS. It has the following input parameter:

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:mensajeWS xmlns:ns2="https://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet/3.27">
    <solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
        <idAplicacion>MIID</idAplicacion>
        <firmaAplicacion>FIRMA</firmaAplicacion>
    </solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
</ns2:mensajeWS>]]>
```

Where **firmaAplicacion** will be obtained as follows:

1.The **idAplicacion** value is passed to *SHA-256*
2.Once the value is obtained in *SHA-256*, the signature is performed in *CADES-T*
3.Finally it goes to *Base64*.

I know how to obtain steps 1 and 3. But the question is the signature in *CADES-T* (I know it has something to do with the **java.security.cert.X509Certificate** library) and I have a public certificate (with a *.cer* extension) and a private one (with a *.p12* extension and its password) but I can't find a way to develop it. Can anybody help me?

get Cades-T signature